# Get results of desired date for Get-AzSecurityAlert

Tags: azure, powershell

I have installed Az.Security module to run Get-AzSecurityAlerts command which provides details of all the security alerts in Security Center of Azure.After running this command I get all alerts but

*I need only alerts before,after or at a particular date*.
But I am not able to modify parameter **ReportedTimeUtc**.

Please help me to modify this parameter in below format to get desired results.

```
Get-AzSecurityAlerts | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt '22-Jun-19 6:16:20 PM' -or -eq '23-Jun-19 8:00:00 PM'}
```

Comment: this doesnt make any sense: `before,after or at a particular date`. this means at any date

Comment: Yes I require results to be generated at desired date which can be either a range or a particular date. It depends on my requirement

Comment: Is it possible your shell is not converting the date string into a `[datetime]` or the property to a datetime type before doing the comparison? `Where-Object 
 { [datetime]$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]'22-Jun-19 6:16:20 PM') }`

Comment: @AdminOfThings This is not working.I am still getting all the security alerts and this filter is not working.Please help and provide another solution.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I found that Where-Object { [datetime]$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]'22-Jun-19 6:16:20 PM') } is not accepting "gt" operator but it is giving successfull results for "like" and "match" operator. Can you help me to get results using these operator to get output for a range of time of a particular date. Like for eg:Where-Object { [datetime]$_.ReportedTimeUtc -like ([datetime]'22-Jun-19 hh:mm:ss AM/PM') }

Comment: Shouldn't the main command be `Get-AzSecurityAlert`? Can you run the following? `$alerts = Get-AzSecurityAlert; $alerts[0].ReportedTimeUtc.GetType()` and provide the output?

Comment: @AdminOfThings Sorry I'm new to powershell.I tried to run $alerts = Get-AzSecurityAlert;$alerts[1].ReportedTimeUtc.GetDateTimeFormat -match '22 June, 2019'  but it's giving no output and the command you provided, it gives below output Is Type:True , IsSerial: True , Name: DateTime , BaseType: System.Valuetype. Please tell me how can I achieve results to get alerts of particular date at any time on that date using above specified command , also what exactly are we trying to achive by running above mentioned command by you.

Comment: Technically, your attempts should have worked provided you have alerts that occurred **after** 22-Jun-19. `Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([datetime]'22-Jun-19 6:16:20 PM')}` should work. Using `-match` or `-like` is not going to be favorable.

Comment: @AdminOfThings "gt" operator is not giving any outputs. Only operators which provided me positive results were 'like' & 'match'.Thanks for the help though.Also is there a way where we can just mention date and provide format of time so that it can provide results of that particular date using like or match operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command format in the comment should work, it works fine on my side.

```
Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:20 AM')}
```

I use the `(Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:20 AM')}).ReportedTimeUtc` to check the `ReportedTimeUtc` of every alert in the result, the time is correct.

[image]

And the `-le` parameter also works,

```
Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -le ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:20 AM')}
```

we can also get the alerts between a time range.

```
Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:20 AM') -and $_.ReportedTimeUtc -le ([DateTime]'7-6-2019 10:00:20 AM')}
```

When using `-eq`, it does not return any result. Not sure why it not work, my workaround is to use a small time range like below, it returns the alert at `7-5-2019 10:00:20 AM`.

```
Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:19 AM') -and $_.ReportedTimeUtc -le ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:21 AM')}
```

Check with `(Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:19 AM') -and $_.ReportedTimeUtc -le ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:21 AM')}).ReportedTimeUtc`, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting below error while using:                                                            
 Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([DateTime]'7-5-2019 10:00:20 AM')}                                                             
 Error ===Cannot convert value "22-6-2019 5:00:0 PM" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @EkanshSingh It should be `Get-AzSecurityAlert | Where-Object {$_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt ([DateTime]'6-22-2019 5:00:00 PM')}`, not `22-6-2019 5:00:00 PM`.

Answer (score 1):

in general in powershell this is how you would filter on multiple conditions:

```
Get-AzSecurityAlerts | Where-Object {
    $_.ReportedTimeUtc -gt '22-Jun-19 6:16:20 PM' -or
    $_.ReportedTimeUtc -eq '23-Jun-19 8:00:00 PM' -or xxx}
```

Comment: I tried this but it provided same results i.e. All the security alerts which are generated from beginning.